# WCF - Sub-class added to a [DataMember] List<BaseClass> causes exception

Tags: wcf, exception, serialization, subclass, datamember

One of my [DataContract] classes contains a [DataMember] which is a List. BaseClass has a few different sub-classes.

Whenever that List contains instances of any sub-class, an exception occurs during/after the Service is returning to the request channel. If the List does not contain any sub-classes, it works fine.

Here is an example of my code (which itself doesn't work):

```
public class BaseClass
{
}
public class BaseClassSub : BaseClass
{
}

[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    List<BaseClass> m_Classes = new List<BaseClass>();

    [DataMember]
    public List<BaseClass> Classes
    {
        get { return m_Classes; }
        set { m_Classes = value; }
    }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyClass GetMyClass();   

}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyClass GetMyClass()
    {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();

        //THIS WORKS!!!!
        //o.Classes = new List<BaseClass>() { new BaseClass() };

        //THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!!
        o.Classes = new List<BaseClass>() { new BaseClassSub() };

        return o;
    }
}
```

I get the following error when debugging:

**The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.6560000'.**

Anyone know how to resolve this issue (getting it to handle sub-classes)?

Comment: Please don't make us guess about the exception. Post the whole exception. Catch it and then post ex.ToString().

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the Data Contract Serializer the types it might encounter. See [Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I just missed your reply as I was posting!

Answer (score 0):

After more searching, I went ahead and put a [KnownType] attribute on BaseClass (see below), and it is now working.

```
[KnownType(typeof(BaseClassSub))]
public class BaseClass
{
}
```

I hope this helps others at least!

Answer (score 0):

DataContrat deserialization does not call constructor and initial values for the members are not assigned

It means that m_Classes will be null after deserializing. Make sure you cover this in your code by either OnDeserialize event or by creating list in getter.